# How to do Perfomance testing with jmeter on visual lansa web application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, correlation, lansa

We are executing performance testing on visual lansa web application

1. we recorded our scenario in jmeter to execute load testing on lansa web application
2. when we playback again , came through some errors
3. where in a xhr post request we found multiple values to post, but now we are unable to find the values from the previous responses to correlate with this request.

We got stuck in this situation. Please suggeat your ideas...

Comment: Record two new versions of the test and compare/correlate them. Edit what you learn into your test.

Answer (score 0):

Given you mention `xhr` requests it might be the case your application relies on [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) technology i.e. it generates and executes some JavaScript-driven HTTP requests when you open the initial page.

As per [JMeter main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if this is the case - you will need to replicate these AJAX calls using either [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) or if JavaScript doesn't generate HTTP calls and just calculates something on client side - mimic this logic using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)